# Unrecognized virtual environment in GitHub Actions with CMake

Tags: cmake, github-actions, virtualenv

I use a virtual environment to cache the installed python packages across multiple CI-jobs. This environment should be used from within CMake (that calls a python script). However, as shown below, CMake does not recognize the virtual environment despite being called after activating the `venv`.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

I created a [minimal (non-)working example](https://github.com/JPietrzykTUD/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/actions/runs/6522815818/job/17712779751). As you will notice, the output of the step "**Print python version**" works as expected:

```
/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/bin/python
Python 3.10.13
/home/runner/work/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/.venv/bin/python
Python 3.10.13
```

When I use CMake to execute the script, I get the following error:

```
-- Found Python3: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.13") found components: Interpreter 
-- 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import jinja2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jinja2'
```

Here, you can find the [Workflow](https://github.com/JPietrzykTUD/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml) and the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/JPietrzykTUD/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/blob/main/CMakeLists.txt):

```yaml
name: 'test'

on:
  push:
    branches: ['main']

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  install-and-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      -
        name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
          cache: "pip"
      - 
        name: Cache virtualenv
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache-venv
        with:
          path: ./.venv/
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-.10-venv-${{ hashFiles('requirements.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-3.10-venv-
      -
        name: 'Install python dependencies for generator'
        run: |
          python -m venv ./.venv
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
        if: steps.cache-venv.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
      - 
        name: 'Print python version'
        run: |
          which python
          python --version
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          which python
          python --version
      - 
        name: 'Run a simple python script directly'
        run: |
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          python main.py
      -
        name: 'Use CMake for the same script'
        run: |
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          cmake -B build -S .
```

`CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(TEST)


set(Python3_FIND_VIRTUALENV FIRST)
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "${PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE}")

execute_process(
        COMMAND "${Python3_EXECUTABLE}" "main.py"
)
```

Comment: Please [edit] to provide the necessary information in the question itself (as text, not pictures or video or a Double Jeopardy quiz). See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Try [`Python3_FIND_VIRTUALENV`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPython3.html#hints) instead of [`Python_FIND_VIRTUALENV`](https://github.com/JPietrzykTUD/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/blob/5ec46ad5d8484abc189b6876a2de3c7d6919d248/CMakeLists.txt#L5).

Comment: @Azeem Thank you for the constructive hint. Unfortunately, it didn't change the result: https://github.com/JPietrzykTUD/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/actions/runs/6523367424/job/17713942769

Comment: In your case, the log `Found Python3: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.13") found components: Interpreter` shows the default path and not the `venv`. Observed that the `setup-python` action was setting these [env vars](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#environment-variables) also. With the default installed Python version, it worked i.e. `Found Python3: /home/runner/work/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/.venv/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.12") found components: Interpreter`.

Comment: Most probably, it has something to do with `Python3_ROOT_DIR` env var that `setup-python` action sets. Didn't find anything on it though in the docs. You might want to dig it deeper to identify the root cause.

Comment: Resetting `Python3_ROOT_DIR` at the command level i.e. `Python3_ROOT_DIR= cmake -B build -S .` works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your logs, even after activating `venv`, the path to Python3 was the default one:

```
-- Found Python3: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.13/x64/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.13") found components: Interpreter
```

whereas, it should be the one from `venv`.

[`Python3_ROOT_DIR` env var among others](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.md#environment-variables) was being set by `actions/setup-python` which I suspected was causing this. Resetting it at the command level made it work:

```bash
Python3_ROOT_DIR= cmake -B build -S .
```

CMake logs and output:

```
-- Found Python3: /home/runner/work/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/ci_pipeline_cmake_meets_python/.venv/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.13") found components: Interpreter 
-- 
Hello World
```

Here's your updated workflow that I used for this test:

```yaml
name: 'test'

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  install-and-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
          # cache: "pip"

      - name: Cache virtualenv
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache-venv
        with:
          path: ./.venv/
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-.10-venv-${{ hashFiles('requirements.txt') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-3.10-venv-

      - name: 'Install python dependencies for generator'
        if: steps.cache-venv.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: |
          python --version
          python -m venv ./.venv
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          if [[ -f requirements.txt ]]; then
            pip install -r requirements.txt
          fi

      - name: 'Print python version'
        run: |
          which python
          python --version
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          which python
          python --version

      - name: 'Run a simple python script directly'
        run: |
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          python main.py

      - name: 'Use CMake for the same script'
        run: |
          source ./.venv/bin/activate
          Python3_ROOT_DIR= cmake -B build -S .
```

Output:

[image: output]

---

Apart from that, I commented `cache: "pip"` for `actions/setup-python` because `pip`'s cache directory had to be cached as well for subsequent workflows. Hopefully, you'll be able to figure that one out.

Comment: Awesome! I would have never thought of that :D Just a minor follow-up question: Is this intended? For me it feels like a bug within actions/setup-python.

Comment: @Hymir: No, it's not a bug. Those env vars are needed for Python to run. I haven't seen this behavior before in the context of `venv`. The documentation of [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindPython3.html) and observing the env vars of the workflow run was very helpful to figure this out. You might want to test this with `set(Python3_FIND_VIRTUALENV ONLY)` as well.